# Gluing of Morse-type trajectories in "Floer Homology of Cotangent bundles"

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, floer-homology

In the paper by A. Abbondadolo and M.Schwarz, *"On the Floer homology of cotangent bundles"* [arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0408280), to prove the desired isomorphism between the Floer homology and the Morse homology of the Lagrangian one looks at the hybrid moduli space problem. Recently I have been trying to understand how one can obtain the gluing of the trajectories on these moduli spaces to prove that we have a chain map between the Floer and Morse complexes.

There are two types of broken trajectories that can happen, either coming from the Morse-type problem or the Floer-type problem as explained in Proposition $3.6$. Let's for now focus on the Morse one which is Proposition $3.9$ part a. The authors claim that the gluing here works as in classical Floer theory. However I am not being able to even see how we can define the pre-gluing. Let's take $u\in \mathcal{M}^{+}(q_1,x)$ and $\bar q\in W^{u}(q_0)\cap W^{s}(q_1)$ now I would like to define a map $\bar q\#_{\rho} u$ such that

$$\lim_{\rho\rightarrow\infty}\bar q\#_{\rho}u=u , \text{in} \hspace{2mm}C^{\infty}_{loc}([0,\infty[\times [0,1],T^*M)$$
there exists a sequence of $\rho_k\rightarrow \infty$ and  $t_k\in ]-\infty,0]$ such that $\phi^{t_k}_{-\nabla_{g,\mathcal{E}}}(\pi (\bar q\#_{\rho_k}u)(0,t))\rightarrow \bar q$ and $\pi(\bar q\#_{\rho}u(0,t))\in W^{u}(q_0)$.

However I am not being able to construct such a map. An idea I had was to use the conditions to create a path $\gamma_{\rho}:[0,\frac{1}{\rho}]\rightarrow M$ such that $\gamma_{\rho}(0)=\bar q$ and $\gamma_{\rho}(\frac{1}{\rho})=\pi(u(0,t))$. Then define

\begin{cases}
      (\bar q(t),p(t)) & s=0\\
       (\gamma_{\rho}(t),p(t))& 0<s<\frac{1}{\rho}\\
      u(s-\frac{1}{\rho}) & s\geq \frac{1}{\rho}
   \end{cases}
where $u(0,t)=(\pi(u(0,t)),p(t))$.
However this will not have the right properties since for the compact set $\{0\}\times [0,1]$ we have $\bar q\#_{\rho}u(0,t)=(\bar q(t),p(t))$ which does not converge to $u(0,t)$ as needed.

I have tried a couple of other things but none of them seemed to work and I am runnig out of ideas. Does anyone have any adivce on how I should do the pre-gluing in this case , or if even I need this kinda of approach to solve the problem ?

Any insight is appreciated, thanks in advance.